# URL rewriting with PHP MySQL .htaccess & GET

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, seo

I have a MySQL database with 5000 items. The table is structured as

id
product-name
content
product-url

You can access a specific product page by going to www.site.com/products/index.php?id=123. The index.php file uses PHP to GET the ID to search the MySQL database and return the appropriate product name and content.

How can I make it so instead of www.site.com/products/index.php?id=123, the URL is rewritten or redirected to www.site.com/products/product-url? If I do it with .htaccess, will the index.php file still be able to know what ID to use to look up the product-url if the ID is not in the URL? Or is there some way to map URLs with PHP and MySQL?

(I'm a noob when it comes to this stuff, so any help will be much appreciated. Thanks.)

Answer (score 4):

You can use .htaccess and a RewriteRule. The following will redirect an SEO URL to index.php with `$_GET['product-url']`. You will need to modify your code to either lookup the product `id` or use the `product-url` directly. Both *should* be unique in your products table.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# redirect product page from SEO URL
RewriteRule ^products/([\w\d-_]+)/?$ products/index.php?product-url=$1 [L]
```

**Note:** I've made the `product_url` to only allow letters, numbers, dashes and underscores. I suggest such a restriction. In addition, the trailing slash is optional. Futhermore, this will not reappend a query string. If you need that you can add the `QSA` flag to the RewriteRule.

Comment: I added a comment about periods in the product-url, but I just deleted the .php extension and now it works like a charm! Thanks so much.

Comment: I don't see your comment. You want periods in the product-url? I would advise against that.